# create adapter for two elements in a same row

Tags: android, listview, xamarin, android-linearlayout, adapter

I'm trying to create an adapter for a listview, which contains two elements in a same row.

The LayoutFile got two linear LinearLayouts [Layout Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IqzKD.jpg) with two images and name

The adapter only fill the first LinearLayout data, and don't show the second LinearLayout.

Someone could help me? Thanks in advance !

XML File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal">
 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewItem"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="175dp"
        android:src="@drawable/icon" />
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="left">
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewTitleItem"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:text="Title"
            android:gravity="center" />
</LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="right">
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewPriceItem"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:text="Price"
            android:gravity="center" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

It is only a View, I want to duplicate it in the same row.

Below the adapter:

```
public ItemAdapter(Activity activity, int layoutResourceId)
    {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
    }

public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        var row = convertView;
        var currentItem = this[position];
        TextView txtViewTitle;
        TextView txtViewPrice;
        ImageView imgViewItem;

        if (row == null)
        {
            var inflater = activity.LayoutInflater;
            row = inflater.Inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

            txtViewTitle = row.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textViewTitleItem);
            txtViewPrice = row.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textViewPriceItem);
            imgViewItem = row.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.imageViewItem);

        } else
            txtViewTitle = row.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textViewTitleItem);
            txtViewPrice = row.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textViewPriceItem);
            imgViewItem = row.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.imageViewItem);

        txtViewTitle.Text = currentItem.Title;
        txtViewPrice.Text = Convert.ToString(currentItem.Price);

        return row;
}
```

Comment: Need to see your xml file that is inflated by your adapter, and maybe the parent layout holding the ListView.

Comment: Please add your adapter code and xml too

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you didn't provide orientation to your parent `LinearLayout`. By default it is horizontal.
That's why its showing only top layout content.
You need to set it as `vertical` to show the entire content in your list.

```
android:orientation="vertical"
```